# Non prime ideal $I$ over ring $R$ implies $R/I$ is not an integral domain

Tags: proof-verification, ideals

> If an ideal $I$ is not prime in a ring $R$ then $R/I$ is not an integral domain

Let $R$ be a ring and $I$ an ideal such that $\exists\ a,b\notin I$ and $ab\in I\ \ \ $ ($I$ is not a prime ideal)

Then $a+I,\ b+I\in R/I$ and $(a+I)(b+I)=ab+I=0+I$ so $R/I$ is not an integral domain.

The contraposition is:

> $R/I$ is an integral domain $\implies$ $I$ is a prime ideal

Proof:

Since $R/I$ is an integral domain $\nexists (a+I),(b+I)\ne 0+I$ s.t. we have that $ab+I=0$

In other words $\nexists a,b\notin I$ s.t. $ab\in I$ so if $ab\in I$ then $a\in I$ or $b\in I$

Is everything ok in these short proofs?

Comment: Content-wise they are ok, but perhaps their presentation could be polished.